# Android JNI native C++ code GetPrimitiveArrayCritical() problem

Tags: android, java-native-interface, arrays

I want to write a native method that could receive data from socket and then write back to a ByteArray which is input parameter from Java. Because I allocate ByteArray in Java side, and pass it to native method, I know I should use GetPrimitiveArrayCritical() to get the pointer of this ByteArray.

However, I still need this procedure to run in a thread, so I use a jbyteArray variable of a struct called socket_loop_native_data to remember this input ByteArray, and use pthread_create() to start a new thread with this struct as input parameter.

Finally, in the main body code of the thread, I use GetPrimitiveArrayCritical() to get the pointer of the previous ByteArray, but it failed...

The error log are :

```
14:09:32.350 Warning dalvikvm 2780  JNI WARNING: 0x4077ab48 is not a valid JNI reference
14:09:32.350 Warning dalvikvm 2780               in Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;.run ()V (GetPrimitiveArrayCritical)
```

The piece of my native code are something like

```
struct socket_loop_native_data {
        pthread_mutex_t thread_mutex;
        pthread_t thread;
        struct pollfd *pollData;
        JavaVM *vm;
        int envVer;
        jobject me;
        jbyteArray javaBuffer;
        int bufferSize;
        jbyte *nativeBuffer;
        char *beginOfBuffer;
        char *endOfBuffer;
        int decodedDataSize;
        bool running;
};

typedef socket_loop_native_data native_data_t;

static jfieldID field_mNativeDataSocket;

static inline native_data_t *get_native_data(JNIEnv *env, jobject object) {
    return (native_data_t *)(env->GetIntField(object, field_mNativeDataSocket));
}

native_data_t *get_SocketLoop_native_data(JNIEnv *env, jobject object) {
    return get_native_data(env, object);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_android_classInitNativeSocket(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz) {
    field_mNativeDataSocket = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "mNativeDataSocket", "I");
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_android_initializeNativeDataNativeSocket(JNIEnv* env, jobject object) {

    native_data_t *nat = (native_data_t *)calloc(1, sizeof(native_data_t));
    if (NULL == nat) {
        LOGD("%s: out of memory!", __FUNCTION__);
        return;
    }
    memset(nat, 0, sizeof(native_data_t));

    pthread_mutex_init(&(nat->thread_mutex), NULL);

    env->SetIntField(object, field_mNativeDataSocket, (jint)nat);

}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_android_startSocketLoopNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jint sock, jbyteArray buffer, jint size) {

    jboolean result = JNI_FALSE;

    socket_loop_native_data *nat = get_native_data(env, object);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(nat->thread_mutex));

    nat->running = false;

    if (nat->pollData) {
        LOGD("trying to start SocketLoop a second time!");
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &(nat->thread_mutex) );
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    nat->pollData = (struct pollfd *)malloc(sizeof(struct pollfd));
    if (!nat->pollData) {
        LOGD("out of memory error starting SocketLoop!");
        goto done;
    }

    memset(nat->pollData, 0, sizeof(struct pollfd));

    nat->pollData[0].fd = sock;
    nat->pollData[0].events = POLLIN;

    env->GetJavaVM( &(nat->vm) );
    nat->envVer = env->GetVersion();

    nat->me = env->NewGlobalRef(object);

    nat->javaBuffer = buffer;
    nat->bufferSize = (int)size;
    nat->decodedDataSize = 0;

    pthread_create(&(nat->thread), NULL, socketLoopMain, nat);
    result = JNI_TRUE;

done:
    if (JNI_FALSE == result) {
        if (nat->me) env->DeleteGlobalRef(nat->me);
        nat->me = NULL;
        if (nat->pollData) free(nat->pollData);
        nat->pollData = NULL;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(nat->thread_mutex));

    return result;
}

static void *socketLoopMain(void *ptr) {

    native_data_t *nat = (native_data_t *)ptr;
    JNIEnv *env;

    JavaVMAttachArgs args;
    char name[] = "SocketLoop";
    args.version = nat->envVer;
    args.name = name;
    args.group = NULL;

    nat->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, &args);

    ...

    nat->nativeBuffer = (jbyte *)(env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical((nat->javaBuffer), NULL));     

    nat->beginOfBuffer = (char *)(&(nat->nativeBuffer[0]));
    nat->endOfBuffer = (char *)(&(nat->nativeBuffer[0])) + (nat->bufferSize);

    ...
}
```

The VM aborting after execute the statement

```
nat->nativeBuffer = (jbyte *)(env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical((nat->javaBuffer), NULL));
```

So... Dose it mean that I could/should not use a jbyteArray variable to remember the input ByteArray and call GetPrimitiveArrayCritical() in another place ???

Or, is anything I forget to do ???

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: Solved : I should use NewGlobalRef().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to "`NewGlobalRef`" your pointer to the byte array `nat->javaBuffer` in your `startSocketLoopNative`.

It should be the cause of your troubles since you're not in the same Thread (new env is created by `AttachCurrentThread` in which, from my experience, all previous non-globals are invalid)

---

*Side note:* Never developped under JNI/Android so your code seems wierd for a guy that always coded J2SE/JNI :)